# SHA256 in T-sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, sha256

Is it possible to generate a SHA-256 hash of a string from a stored procedure in Sql Server 2008?

For deployment reasons, I'd prefer it in TSQL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update**: SQL Server 2012 [HASHBYTES()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) now supports SHA-256 and SHA-512 out of the box.

> ```
> HASHBYTES ( '<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )
>
> <algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512
> ```

Sure. You can do it in TSQL, but it will be much easier to implement it as a [CLR Stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx).

Here's an actual example, that simply uses the .NET Framework types: [Let's Hash a BLOB](http://web.archive.org/web/20171003225612/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/michael_coles/archive/2009/04/16/13253.aspx)

Comment: Hi Mitch thanks for that. For deployment reasons, I'd prefer it in TSQL. I'll clarify.

Comment: It's going to be considerably harder to write and less perform less well in TSQL ...

Comment: Just an FYI, SQL 2012 added support for SHA-256. You just pass SHA_256 as the algorithm.

Comment: The TSQL link is not usable anymore; it has restricted access without anyway to register new user accounts. http://sqlblog.com/Msgs/default.aspx?MessageID=29 However you can find the original article at http://web.archive.org/web/20171003225612/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/michael_coles/archive/2009/04/16/13253.aspx

Answer (score 4):

SHA256, SHA512 in SQL SERVER 2008 OR SQL SERVER 2005!

You can do if you use the fnEnCryptSHA.dll!!

```
USE [master] GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1 GO RECONFIGURE GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY InnoDll FROM 'C:\sqltip\fnEnCryptSHA.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET= SAFE GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetStringToSha256 (@Str nvarchar(1000)) RETURNS varbinary(8000) AS EXTERNAL NAME InnoDll.fnEnCryptSHA.GetStringToSha256 GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetBinaryToSha256 (@Str varbinary(8000)) RETURNS varbinary(8000) AS EXTERNAL NAME InnoDll.fnEnCryptSHA.GetBinaryToSha256 GO

SELECT dbo.fnGetStringToSha256('abc')

SELECT dbo.fnGetBinaryToSha256(0x9F04F41A848514162050E3D68C1A7ABB441DC2B5)
```

Comment: Where can you find that DLL?

Comment: I didn't realize you could call a .dll so easily through SQL Server. You could also just throw your own SHA-256 hashing method into a class/.dll and call it via SQL. Very cool, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does it HAVE to be SHA-256.  There is a SQL `HASHBYTES()` function that can do SHA, SHA1, MD5 etc.

*(Of course it depends on if you just want a hash representation of a value, or to securely store valuable data.)*

Comment: Added in case (like me) I was searching for any native HASH function in SQL server and they come across this question.  It would imply that CLR is the only way to provide a HASH function.

Comment: CLR Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416249/hashing-a-string-with-sha256