# sha256 function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hash, sha256, sha

Is there a built-in sha256 function in SQL Server? I can't find a sha256 T-SQL function source code either. Anyone who has an alternative?

Comment: See the answer here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954784/sha256-in-t-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021992/i-want-to-get-hexadecimal-value-off-a-binary-value-removing-0x-from-it

Answer (score 45):

SQL Server 2012 supports SHA2_256 and SHA2_512.

```
 SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','something')
```

Comment: This returns NULL in server server 2019.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx), but it supports only up to SHA-1 (160 bytes)

FYI Hashing is **not** encrypting. It is irreversible. Encryption is a process that is reversible to get the original data.

Reference for [SHA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)

> SHA-2 is a set of cryptographic **hash** functions (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512)

---

Here is a [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/6002f5a4-19a0-4a11-a569-e112375d3efa/) about adding a salt to hashes

As for 256-byte hashing function - there isn't one built in.

Comment: yes, it's for hashing random salt + password

Comment: it doesn't support sha256 yet.