# I want to get hexadecimal value off a binary value removing 0x from it

Tags: t-sql, hash, sql-server-2012, binary, sha1

I have a binary value in SQL server that contains SHA1 code like :

```
0xC06DCADF544BC3D6ECE7C64F485D2846E7A93F55
```

I want to remove `0x` from it.

When I calculate SHA1 of the string the output starts with `0x` and I take it in a binary variable. I want to store it in a column after removing `0x` from it.

Comment: Since I have asked the question and pondered quite a lot about it, I think what I need to do is get the hexadecimal value out of it, so I asked the wrong question, but I still need to know how to do that. Please help!!!

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the terms Hex and Binary. They are not different here. You cannot get hex values out of `0xC06D..` since it is already hex values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the datatype of the column you are storing the binary value in is `BINARY` or `VARBINARY`, then you can't remove the leading `0x` because then the value would be a sting and no longer binary. The `0x` isn't a part of the value, it is an indication that the value is binary and not string.

If the datatype of the field being inserted into is a string type (`CHAR` / `VARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `NVARCHAR`) then you can convert the binary value to a string using the `CONVERT` function while specifying a "style" of `2`:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 0xC06DCADF544BC3D6ECE7C64F485D2846E7A93F55, 2)
-- C06DCADF544BC3D6ECE7C64F485D2846E7A93F55
```

Comment: Hey I have edited the question, didnt think it through that was stupid. the column in which I have to insert it contains hexadecimal values. I have SHA1 code in a variable type binary. I want hexadecimal code out of the binary variable, or if there is some way for me to use a variable type that only takes hexadecimal directly without a 0x from HASBYTES()

Comment: @MagicBeans That doesn't make any sense. Hex and Binary are synonyms. `0x` denotes that the value is binary, which is displayed using hex values. What you have is already hex values. The only way to get rid of the `0x` is to convert it to a string as I showed in my answer.