# MD5 Hash Values being prefixed with '0x'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have access to a database (SQL 2008 R2) which allows file uploads.  Within a table it has a column called ‘hash_key’ which I believe to be the md5 checksum.

I’m trying to include some logic in something I’m writing which will also work out the md5 file.

The trouble is the two systems are producing subtly different hash values for the same file.  The system would return this:

```
0x098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6
```

And my function (and also some online ones) would return this for the same file

```
098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6
```

As you can see the only different is the first two (0x) characters.  Is this down to how the database is storing the value?  The database field is binary(16)

Am I safe to just ignore the first two characters when doing the comparison?

Comment: `0x` indicates a binary sequence, and you will need a `byte[]` for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SQL Function HASHBYTES() with 2 arguments:

```
HASHBYTES('MD5', 'yourString') => 0x349DA9BFF6660DAD199ACF68D353DBA3
```

Or you can use CONVERT() with 3 arguments:

```
CONVERT(varchar(32),HASHBYTES('MD5', 'yourString'),2) => 349DA9BFF6660DAD199ACF68D353DBA3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the `0x` prefix is that the database is (correctly) returning a hexadecimal value. In your code, if you cast your value to hex, the two values will match, as `0x` isn't actually part of the value, it's just a type identifier

Comment: Thanks, converting to hex produces this : 3039384636424344343632314433373343414445344538333236323742344636

Answer (score 0):

Refer solution in [I want to get hexadecimal value off a binary value removing 0x from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021992/i-want-to-get-hexadecimal-value-off-a-binary-value-removing-0x-from-it)

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),HashedVal2,2)
```

Do a varchar conversion before storing values

```
SELECT * , CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),HashedVal2,2)
FROM
(
SELECT * , HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',MyVal) AS HashedVal2
FROM OLEDB_MyTable
)T
```