# SHA256 base 64 hash generation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sha256, sha

I need to generate a **SHA256 base 64** hash from a table in SQL server but I can't find that algorithm in the [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) HASHBYTES arguments.

Is there a way to generate it directly in SQL Server?

**Duplicate disclamer:**

My question is not duplicate of [SHA256 in T-sql stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954784/sha256-in-t-sql-stored-procedure) as I am looking for the SHA256 **base 64** version of the algorithm which is not listed in the page.

**Numeric Example**

I have this query result in SQL Server

> Start date,End date,POD,Amount,Currency
>
> 2016-01-01,2016-12-31,1234567890,12000,EUR

this give me the following string (using *concatenate* function)

> 2016-01-012016-12-31123456789012000EUR

whit [this convertion tool](http://approsto.com/sha-generator/) I get the following hash

> GMRzFNmm90KLVtO1kwTf7EcSeImq+96QTHgnWFFmZ0U

that I need to send to a customer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SHA256 in T-sql stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954784/sha256-in-t-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: @Tanner, as written in the question I am looking for the SHA256 base 64 algorithm, not the SHA256 HEX. For this reason it is not duplicate.

Comment: Getting binary output from ordinary SHA256 and encode it into base64 doesn't fit? What is the difference, then? Can you provide a link to a more detailed description?

Comment: @RogerWolf I added a numeric example. At the moment I am writing users have an Excel file with VBA to generate the hash but I'd like to know if it is possibile to make it in SQL Server.

Comment: This isn't a separate algorithm, it's just getting the SHA256 bytes and then [encoding them in Base64](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32231832/4137916).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've tried to convert the concatenated string to SHA256 and then to Base64 but I get a different hash. "18c47314d9a6f7428b56d3b59304dfec47127889aafbde904c78275851666745" from concat to SHA256 and "MThjNDczMTRkOWE2Zjc0MjhiNTZkM2I1OTMwNGRmZWM0NzEyNzg4OWFhZmJkZTkwNGM3ODI3NTg1 MTY2Njc0NQ=" from SHA256 to Base64.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, the generator link you provided outputs the base64 representation in not exactly correct format. Namely, it omits the [padding sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_Padding). Though theoretically optional, padding is mandatory in MS SQL Server (tested on 2012 and 2016 versions).

With this in mind, the following code gives you what you need:

```
declare @s varchar(max), @hb varbinary(128), @h64 varchar(128);

select @s = '2016-01-012016-12-31123456789012000EUR';

set @hb = hashbytes('sha2_256', @s);
set @h64 = cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@hb"))', 'varchar(128)');

select @hb as [BinaryHash], @h64 as [64Hash];
```

Apart from the aforementioned padding, there is another caveat for you to look for. Make sure that the input string is always of the same type, that is, either always `varchar` or always `nvarchar`. If some of your hashes will be calculated from ASCII strings and some from UTF-16, results will be completely different. Depending on which languages are used in your system, it might make sense to always convert the plain text to `nvarchar` before hashing.

Comment: I get null for both columns. I have MS SQL Server 2012 and when I execute this parts of code I get null value, because sql hashbytes function supports following hash algorythms: 'MD2', 'MD4', 'MD5', 'SHA' and 'SHA1'.

Comment: @oknevermind, are you testing it on the same input data? If not, make sure your input does not exceed 8000 bytes.

Comment: For the input I am using nvarchar type data. For example, I use input string 'ppp_001#Wd!!'

Comment: @oknevermind, I don't think you use 2012 version of the server. Docs state clearly that SHA2 is supported for 2012: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415(v=sql.110).aspx Have you checked the `print @@version`, what does it say?

Comment: @@Roger, sorry, my mistake. You are right. Version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1). But, version of SQL Management Studio on my work computer is 2012. I am read info of this link that you sent. Thanks for explanation.