# Function in SQL Server to handle HMAC-SHA256 encryption?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, hmac

Is there a function I can use in SQL Server to handle HMAC-SHA256 encryption? I see examples of SHA256([SHA256 in T-sql stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954784/sha256-in-t-sql-stored-procedure)) using HASHBYTES but need a way to handle HMAC-SHA256 within SQL Server.

Comment: If the algoritm isn't natively supported in SQL Server, you'll likely need to look into using a CLR function.

Comment: Link for .NET Api for CLR Function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Also define "handle".